# How to get dockercli in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I was able to install docker on Windows Server 2016 using these commands:

```
Install-Module DockerMsftProvider -Force
Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
```

But when I tried to pull one of the images that uses Linux, I got this error:

> Using default tag: latest latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries.

I searched and understood that I need to switch to Linux container, but all commands needs dockercli, and I couldn't find it in the folder I installed docker in.

How can I get dockercli in Windows Server 2016, and does updating to Windows Server 2019 gets me any benefit?

Comment: Can you provide us the output of `winver`, the way you want to use Docker, requires 16299 which is 1709.  I suspect since you are indeed running Windows Server 2016 you don't meet the system requirements for Docker.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get dockercli in Windows Server 2016

dockercli requires Windows Server 1709 (10.0 16299) or newer.  Windows Server 2016 (10.0 14393) is based on 1607.

> LCOW support is available in Windows 10 Fall Creators Update and in Windows Server 1709. The simplest way to try it out on Windows 10 is to install the edge variant of Docker for Windows (details). On Windows Server 1709, install EE preview.

Source: [Preview: Linux Containers on Windows](https://www.docker.com/blog/preview-linux-containers-on-windows/)

> Would updating to Windows Server 2019 gets me any benefit?

Windows Server 2019 (10.0.17763) is based on 1809 and would indeed satisfy the requirements for LCOW support.  **There is no upgrade path to Windows Server 1709 from Windows Server 2016.**